# BoundingBox of VISIBLE part of GameObject regarding a given camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, computer-vision, bounding-box

I want to find the 2D bounding box (BB) of the visible part of an Game-object in Unity3D.**

Thanks to having no reputation i cant post images, so here are links to Imgur:

**Starting Point:** [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJ7ld.jpg)
Showing the initial scene camera. For example i want to get the BB of the wheels of the passing car.

**Goal:** [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUCgu.jpg)
Showing the quite small BB i want to get in an efficient way. The method used is very costly and i want to avoid it. Its works on a segmented version of the input picture, looking similar to this: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1QUJ.jpg).

**Current Approach:**
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dnNR.jpg)
This uses the bounds of all GameObjects (GO) tagged as wheels and calls a function similar like this:

```
Rect GetBoundingBox(GameObject go, Camera camera, float margin = 0f)
{
    Rect rect = new Rect(-1f, -1f, -1f, -1f);
    Vector3[] v; // Vertices

    // Object is behind camera
    if (camera.WorldToScreenPoint(go.GetComponentInChildren<Renderer>().bounds.center).z < 0)
        return rect;

    // get first mesh filter
    v = go.GetComponentInChildren<MeshFilter>().mesh.vertices;

    // maybe the game object hast no mesh yet... and is empty
    if (v.Length < 1 || v == null)
        return rect;

    for (int i = 0; i < v.Length; i++)
    {
        //World space
        v[i] = go.transform.TransformPoint(v[i]);
        //GUI space
        v[i] = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(v[i]);
        v[i].y = Screen.height - v[i].y;
    }

    Vector3 min = v[0];
    Vector3 max = v[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < v.Length; i++)
    {

        min = Vector3.Min(min, v[i]);
        max = Vector3.Max(max, v[i]);
    }

    //Construct a rect of the min and max positions and apply some margin
    rect = Rect.MinMaxRect(min.x, min.y, max.x, max.y);

    // apply optional margin
    rect.xMin -= margin;
    rect.xMax += margin;
    rect.yMin -= margin;
    rect.yMax += margin;

    return rect;
}
```

Two problems appear.

1. Its getting all BB even if the GO is not visible by the camera.
2. Even if its visible, the boundaries are as large as the GO it self, not as the visible part.

**I am very happy about every hint in a good direction!!**

For interested people the background is the development of an application to generate/simulate labeled training data for an deep learning project.

Comment: you can try to raycast against each vertex of the mesh and check if it hits a collider belonging to that mesh, but its probably not going to be faster

Comment: How would you do that? i cant find a way to check if its belonging to the corresponding mesh. And would you mind to up vote the question, so i can post images? nobody will answer such question with the clicking over head...

Comment: you take each vertex of the mesh / mesh collider, transform it to world space using its transform, create a ray towards it using a camera, than use Physics.Raycast towards it and check if hits the collider you expect or another one. this will only work reasonably well for dense meshes though - and will be quite slow